# Crystal Reports - Add a new field to a stored procedure and make it available in the IDE?

Tags: crystal-reports

I added a new field to a stored procedure.

How do I get it to be available in Crystal Reports without resetting the datasource in the database expert?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Verify Database** works, but you have more control over things if you use the **Set Datasource Location** (found in Database > Set Datasource Location) to update the report after a proc change:

1. Open the Set Datasource Location dialogue (Database > Set Datasource Location).
2. Left click/select the procedure to update in the **Current Data Source** pane
3. Navigate to the procedure on the server to update with in the Replace with pane

   - Use the Current Connections leaf if you've already ran a report within the Crystal Reports Developer application. It can take a while for the pane to refresh.
   - Otherwise, navigate to the Create New Connection > [Database] leaf.  If using Oracle, you will be prompted for the TNS, user and password for the connection
4. Click the now enabled **Update** button

This is where you set the **Overridden Table Qualifier Name**, which is essential for Oracle when a single report is to support multiple environments using the same TNS name.

Answer (score 3):

Database Menu -> Verify Database

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/programming-life/adding-new-fields-to-stored-procedure-and-updating-it-in-crystal-reports-30072

Answer (score 2):

Click on Database -> Verify Database

Then right click on data source and refresh