# crystal report field explorer not showing newly added field in stored procedure

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a crystal report with stored procedure , it is working fine.  but  when i am add new field in  stored procedure that field dose not shown in crystal report    i tried update database schema by using verify database but that doesn't help

Comment: Please see [new field & stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647363): if there is something not addressed, please edit your question with the specifics.

Comment: Do you put your credentials when you verify database? https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/georgealexander/adding-new-fields-to-stored-procedure-and-updating-it-in-crystal-reports-021709