# Error When Printing Crystal Report That Uses SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report created that uses a SQL Server stored procedure as the data source.  The stored procedure has one parameter.  When the code below runs I get "Database logon failed" at the obj.PrintToPrinter line.

If I remove the stored procedure from the report and replace it with the same tables used in the stored procedure and use the same parameter, no error.  The report prints with no issues!

Any help would be appreciated, I'd really like to use stored procedures for our reports.  Thanks!

```
        ReportDocument obj = new ReportDocument();


        string m_rptname = "C:\\Reports\\MyReport.rpt";
        obj.Load(m_rptname);

        obj.SetParameterValue(0, "123456");

        foreach (Table tbl in obj.Database.Tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo tli = tbl.LogOnInfo;
            tli.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "myServer";
            tli.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "myUser";
            tli.ConnectionInfo.Password = "myPass";
            tli.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "myDB";

            tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tli);
        }

        //The line below is where the error happens for stored proc only
        obj.PrintToPrinter(2, false, 0, 0);
        obj.Close();
        obj.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things that you may or may not have already tried...

1. In order to isolate the problem to Crystal Reports, have you tried writing a function to execute the procedure with a direct SQL connection?  This would allow you to test your credentials and SQL permissions.
2. I don't see anything in your connection settings about Integrated Security, you may want to double check that.  Since you are passing a username/password, I am assuming you are NOT using Windows Authentication and may need to Integrated Security = false
3. Does your report have any sub reports?  If so, you will need to set the connection info like you did with your tables.
4. Check to see if your data source is out of sync with your database.  To do this from the report designer, select Database -> Verify Database.

If these options do not work, let me know and I can do some more digging.  Crystal reports are great once you get the "gotchas" out of the way.

Comment: Thanks, all is good with the connections b/c I can run the report and print as long as I don't use a stored procedure in the source of the report.  If I drag in all of the same tables used by the stored procedure, and then run the same c# code the report prints as expected.  No subreports, no extra anything at this point since I've slimmed the report down to a few fields being returned from a select statement and one parameter.  It doesn't make any sense...maybe I've been using SSRS for too long, where things just seem to work!

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback Scope Creep, we've made some progress.  Per your recommendation #2, we investigated this further.  We were actually able to make things work, but it was by trial and error...so I'm hoping you can shed some light.  If we go into Database Expert and Integrated Security is True, and then in the c# app we use Integrated Security is False, the report using a stored procedure finally works.  What's puzzling is why?  Any ideas?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working!

Integrated Security = True indicates to SQL Server that the currently Windows account credentials should be used for authentication.
Integrated Security = False indicates to SQL Server that the the connection will be authenticated with a SQL User Username/Password combination.

What it sounds like, is that you accidently mixed  the two, which does not work.  If Integrated Security is set to True, you cannot send in a username/password.  If it is set to false, you must send in a username/password

Comment: The only one way I was able to "fix" this problem with stored procedure(s) was to create a new connection with integrated security and change the "Datasource location" for the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases Verify Database is not sufficient. Stored procedures tend to be "sticky" with Crystal Reports. When adding or updating a stored procedure I usually have to reset the Datasource Location. This is found at Database > Set Datasource Location.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647103/crystal-reports-add-a-new-field-to-a-stored-procedure-and-make-it-available-in)